# How to return to netrw from a file

Tags: buffers, netrw, path

Suppose that I'm editing a file, then I press `:w` to store it. And then I use `:e.` to navigate its containing folder in the netrw. Suppose its containing folder is `./A/B/`. In netrw, I open a file with path `./D/E`.

My question is when I enter into the file `./D/E`, how can I return to `./D/` or `./A/B/`?

I tried `:b#`, but only to return to the previous edited file, not to the netrw. I know that I can use `:e.` again to return to `./A/B/` since it's current path. Is there any way to return to `./D/`, the containing folder of the currently being edited file?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
:E[xplore]
```

does the same thing as `:e %:h`, and is shorter to type.

If you look up `:help :Explore`, you can see that there are also variations to open the directory of the current file in a new tab or split instead of in the current window.

Comment: `:E` is no less convenient than `<C-o>`. But `:E` is easier to remember since I can group it together with `:e`, `:sp.`, `:vs.` etc.

Comment: Seems `:Rex` is better because it remembers last position in netrw.

Answer (score 4):

`:e %:h` navigates to the directory of the current file. See `:help expand()` for more info. Tim Pope's [Vinegar](https://github.com/tpope/vim-vinegar) plugin essentially binds `-` to this, and introduces a few small other conveniences.

You could also use `<c-o>` to navigate to the previous jump/file shown in the current window.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of commands in netrw for directory navigation.  Some that come to mind:  `:Rexplore` (to return from a file to netrw); `:help netrw-qb` will inform you of netrw's history mechanism (u, U), `:help g:netrw_keepdir`, etc.